# How to rewrite all routes not going to a specific subdirectory to a different subdirectory in nginx?

Tags: nginx, directory

My site content (which is currently kept in /public_html loosely) is under a Mercurial repository, so I would like it to have its own directory. Since my wiki is under /public_html/wiki, I am trying to come up with routing logic that will route all requests not going to mysite.com/wiki to /public_html/content.

Currently I have:

```
server {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    listen 80;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com;                                                                                                                                                                                             
    access_log /www/mysite.com/logs/access.log;                                                                                                                                                                                             
    error_log /www/mysite.com/logs/error.log;                                                                                                                                                                                               
    root /www/mysite.com/public_html;                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    location / {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        index index.html index.htm index.php;                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

    location ~/\.hg                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        deny all;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

    location ~ \.php$ {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        try_files  $uri  /404.html;                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        fastcgi_index index.php;                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /www/mysite.com/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;                                                                                                                                                      
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
}
```

I tried `try_files $uri /content$uri` but that just made it loop back in on itself with rewriting. I also couldn't catch /wiki prefix with a location block because I would have had to stop the pattern matching at that point, preventing the .php from being matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com;
    access_log /www/mysite.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /www/mysite.com/logs/error.log;
    root /www/mysite.com;

    location / {
        try_files /public_html$uri =404;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location /wiki {
        index index.php;
    }

    location ~/\.hg
    {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just determine `$document_root` for every location and use this variable in location for php/fastcgi:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com;
    access_log /www/mysite.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /www/mysite.com/logs/error.log;

    location / {
        root /www/mysite.com/public_html;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location /wiki {
        root /www/mysite.com/wiki;
        index index.php;
    }

    location ~/\.hg {
            deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files  $uri  /404.html;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: This kept blowing up on the `try_files  $uri  /404.html;` line; `$uri` failed and it went to 404. I eventually found something that worked that I will post.